# Unprovable unprovability of $\forall x\in X:P(x)$

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Consider statements of the form $\forall x\in X:P(x)$. Is it possible that such a statement is proven to be unprovable?

I think not, and here is my argument: if we proved that the statement is unprovable, we would also prove that we will never be able to find a counter-example (an $x$ for which $\neg P(x)$, because that would disprove the statement), therefore proving the statement.

Is my argument correct?

Is it possible, that the statement is unprovable, even though we cannot prove its unprovability?

Comment: Your argument isn't quite formal enough to be correct or incorrect.  You need to specify both the formal system you're working under, or at least its properties (otherwise 'provable' has little to no meaning!) and the domains being quantified over.  In the broad, statements of the form $\forall x:P(x)$ can certainly be unprovable, but their unprovability for systems like PA is contingent on the system's consistency; otherwise _every_ statement in the formal system is provable!

Comment: With very strong restrictions on the shape of $P(x)$, your argument is reasonable. But in general, can't say, any sentence can be made of shape $\forall x P(x)$.

Comment: It may be the case that all models of your axiom system are free of counterexamples and yet your chosen axioms and the natural rules of inference are incapable of deriving $\forall x P(x)$.

Comment: @Dave: Here is just side comment. If you can prove that a universal statement is neither provable nor refutable in, say, PA, then the statement is actually true in the natural numbers, because otherwise, PA would be able to find a counterexample. This is perhaps in the same spirit as your argument.

Comment: Why all the subtle answers when the OP has mixed up provability and disprovability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your informal argument is not right. If  $\forall\,x\in X \cdot P(x)$ is unprovable, it does not follow that $\lnot P(x)$ is unsatisfiable. $\forall\,x\in X \cdot P(x)$ could be unprovable because it is false, e.g.,  $\forall\,x\cdot x \not= x$. It is true in an informal sense that a proof that a universal sentence is not *disprovable* constitutes a proof that it is true.

As for your last question: it needs to be asked in a more rigorous setting. At an informal level, there are all sorts of things that we can't prove. Boolos's excellent book *The Logic of Provability* provides a rigorous account of the logic of provability for theories of arithmetic.